# How to correctly import a JAR from an external project, using Gradle in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, import, jar, build.gradle

I am attempting to import classes from an external project by using Gradle to declare a dependency on the generated JAR file. However, something (possibly "moi") is not working correctly.

This is an image of the source JAR file and the folder structure where it lives.
[image]

This is a screenshot of the JAR's manifest, so it looks like the target classes are being included.
[image]

And, here is an image showing the dependency declared in the build.gradle file, and the Gradle panel showing the dependencies. And, frustratingly, the error indicating the source package does not exist.
[image]

As an "oh, by the way", much of the package structure (i.e., "mil.navy.demo.xml") is replicated in the project where the JAR is being imported into. I don't know if this is problematic (doesn't seem like it should be), but...

If I figure it out, I will post a solution. But, for now, I seem to be chasing an elusive (and, all-too-likely) error in how I'm using Gradle to declare/import the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrey for pointing me in the right direction. I am unsure of exactly why (I guess I should read more of the referenced question), but using a relative path (shown below), works. Either this is a "weirdness of Gradle", or I am getting the absolute path incorrect, but the build script shown below works correctly to import the requisite JAR file...
[image]